# convert float to short and back to float

Tags: casting, floating-point

I am using C programming, and I need to cast a float variable to short variable and casting it back into float variable.

At length: I am receiving 32 bit of data, than performs a logarithmic action on them. the value decrease significantly.
Than I want to send them to protocol, to another machine through short variable. The second machine, need to read the data as float and not as int.

For example, I want to send 15,153,123 (decimal) -> after log: 7.180502148 -> send it as short by saving the precision as possible: 7180502148 (again, as possible) -> convert it back to float: 7.180502148 -> back to decimal: 15,153,123. I am stuck on the casting from floating point to short (after log action)

I need to do the casting fast as possible. without unnecessary commands.
I dont have use in the exponents and significand, just the casting.

Thank you

Comment: Your title says `int`, your question says `short`. Clarify what you want to do. It is possible to copy the bytes of a `float` into the bytes of a same-sized unsigned integer type and examine them, or to examine them one at a time through a pointer to `unsigned char`. Decoding the exponent and the signifcand (“significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation; “mantissa” is an old word for the fraction portion of a logarithm) from the bytes representing it requires knowledge of the format. What format are you using?…

Comment: … If you do not know what `float` format you are using, what C implementation are you using? What is the name of the compiler? What do you want to do with the exponent and significand? Just display them, or something else?

Comment: You need to specify the operation you want performed. “Conversion” is a term used too broadly to mean several things. The `float` 3.75 could be converted to integer 3, preserving its represented value as much as possible. The `float` 3.75 could be converted to its representation, 0x40700000, showing its encoding. The `float` 3.75 could be converted to the parts of its representation 0 for the sign, 1 for the exponent (encoded as 128), and 1.875 for the significand (principally encoded as 0x700000). Which of these do you want, or do you want something else?

Comment: Also, `float32_t` is 32 bits, but `short` is commonly 16 bits. (I do not know what it is in Keil for MDK-Arm.) How do you expect to convert 32 bits to 16 bits?

Comment: To help explain what you want, show several sample input values and corresponding output values.

Comment: I will explain myself.
I am receiving 32 bit of data, than performs a logarithmic action on them. the value decrease significantly.
Than I want to send them to protocol, to another machine through short variable.
The second machine, need to read the data as float and not as int.
for example, I want to send 15,153,123 (decimal) -> after log: 7.180502148 -> send it as short by saving the precision as possible: 7180502148 (again, as possible) -> convert it back to float: 7.180502148 -> back to decimal: 15,153,123.

I am stuck on the casting from floating point to short (after log action)

Comment: Is your goal to communicate “as much as possible” of the original `float` value through 16 bits? In other words, you are not required to use a logarithm; you can use any method that communicates the data? If so, then is there a limit on the range of the floating-point values? E.g., are they all under 2^24 in magnitude or all positive or something like that?

Comment: Generally, it will not be possible to recover 15,153,123 from transmitting through 16 bits; some information will be lost. If the full `float` sign and exponent must be retained, then the solution is to round the `float` value to 8 significant bits (7 encoded in the significand), making a total of 16 (1 sign, 8 exponent, 7 significand), send that, and reconstruct the number. This can be done with a Dekker-Veltkamp split. (Of, if you just want to truncate, not round, it can be done just by taking the high 16 bits of the floating-point encoding.) For 15,153,123, you will get 15,138,816.

Comment: Yes, I thought of a logarithmic number, because it reduces the original value so that it can not pass it by 16 bits.
The values are all positive and under 2^24.

I know some data will be lost, I want to preserve it as possible, but its not critical if it will show 940 instead of 950/960.
The problem of saving the high 16 bits, is at low number, like 950. it will displayed as 0.
I will review Dekker-Veltkamp split.
I prefer the precision will be save in low numbers than high numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Veltkamp-Dekker-Boldo to round the significand to seven bits, and this will produce a value with zeros in the low 16 bits of its IEEE-754 binary32 representation. Here is a demonstration:

```
/*  This uses the Veltkamp-Dekker-Boldo algorithm to split a floating-point
    number into high and low parts.  We take only the high part and use 0x1p17
    to remove 17 bits from the significand, leaving 24-17 = 7 bits.

    We assume:

        The float type is IEEE 754 "single", also known as binary64, with a
        24-bit significand.

        x * (0x1p17 + 1) does not overflow.

        Round-to-nearest mode is used.

    Casts are used to, in the terminology of the C standard, "discard" excess
    precision.  The intent is for all operations to be performed in the float
    type.
        
    Credits:

        Per Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic, Muller et al, 2010, pages
        132-133, Dekker proved the algorithm for radix 2 implicitly assuming no
        overflow or underflow occurs, and Boldo provided it for any radix
        provided C*x does not overflow.  (C is the constant multiplier, b^s+1,
        where b is the base and s is the number of bits going to the lower
        part.)  From other sources, seems Berhard W. Veltkamp published in
        1968, Theodorus J. Dekker provided radix 2 in 1971, Sylvie Boldo proved
        general radix in 2006.
*/
static float Round7(float x)
{
    float d = x * (float) (0x1p17f + 1);
    return d - (float) (d - x);
}


#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


static void Try(float x)
{
    //  Round x to only 7 bits in the significand.
    float y = Round7(x);

    /*  At this point, in the IEEE-754 format, y should have a sign bit,
        eight exponent bits, seven "live" bits in the hight part of the
        significand, and 16 zero bits in the low part.
    */

    //  Reinterpret the bytes of the float as an unsigned integer.
    uint32_t u = (union { float f; uint32_t u; }) {y} .u;

    //  Show the transformation from float to rounded float to unsigned short.
    printf("%a (%g) -> %a (%g) -> 0x%04" PRIx32 ".\n", x, x, y, y, u >> 16);

    //  Test whether the low bits are zero.
    if (u & 0xffffu)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error, low bits are 0x%" PRIx32 ".\n", u & 0xffffu);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    Try(15153123.f);
}
```

If seven bits in the significand (that is total, including the leading bit) is insufficient, you might squeeze another bit or three out of the exponent if you do not need to support very low exponents. For example, since you have already said values are less than 2<sup>24</sup>, if you only need exponents from −8 to +23, you could squeeze the exponent from eight bits to five with some more manipulation of the number.