# How can i use just 16 bits of presicion in the floating point?

Tags: c++, architecture, floating-point, bit

i want to use just 16 bits in the floating point format (5 bits for the exponent and 10 bits for the mantisa).

With this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float_16 value = 10000;
    cout<<value;

}
```

I need the console to prints 1250 because the 16 float format, no 10000. Is this possible? no matters the language.

Comment: There is no native type as you describe.  You will likely need to define your own struct/class type (or find a 3rd party one) that manipulates bits directly as you have described.

Comment: There is an IEEE [16 bit float format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format).  Same as you describe, 5 bit exponent and 10 bit mantissa.  But that format absolutely can store `10000` and certainly would not change it to `1250`.  It's not clear to me what you are asking here.

Comment: If you are using Clang, you can use `__fp16` for a 16-bit floating-point format. Just change `float_16` in your sample code to `__fp16`. For GCC, it appears to be available [only for ARM targets](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.3/gcc/Half-Precision.html). However, even with 16-bit floating-point, the program will output “10000” because 10000 is representable in 16-bit floating-point: 10000 is 1.001110001 (base 2) • 2^13, which is ten bits in the significand and an exponent in the normal range −14 to 15.

Comment: Incidentally, “significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic. Significands are linear. Also, note that although ten bits are used for the primary encoding of the significand, the mathematical significand of the format is 11 bits, since one bit is encoded via the exponent field.

Comment: If your compiler does support 16-bit floating-point, you can use [the Veltkamp-Dekker-Boldo algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67586015/convert-float-to-short-and-back-to-float/67629299#67629299) to round `double` results to 16-bit. (Using `double` guarantees no double-rounding errors in elementary operations when rounding to half-precision. `float` may too, but I would have to check whether 24 bits are enough to avoid double-rounding when going to 11.)